# how to create list of Years in the dropdown using react js JSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I want to create a list of the Years in react JSX

I have a code for the Jquery, please have a look below.

```
var minOffset = 0, maxOffset = 60; // Change to whatever you want
var thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var select = $('<select>');

for (var i = minOffset; i <= maxOffset; i++) {
    var year = thisYear - i;
    $('<option>', {value: year, text: year}).appendTo(select);
}

select.appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DhpBg/739/

Answer (score 16):

First, generate all the required years in an array

```
const year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
const years = Array.from(new Array(20),( val, index) => index + year);
```

Once you have the years, you can iterate over the array and list it in `select` control.

Consider following code snippet

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  const year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  this.years = Array.from(new Array(20),(val, index) => index + year);
}

render() {
  return(
    ...
    <select>
     {
       this.years.map((year, index) => {
         return <option key={`year${index}`} value={year}>{year}</option>
       })
     }
    </select>
    ...
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Looks good, but is that missing `return` before the start of the option tag in the map function?

Comment: Ah, right, I missed the return statement. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This solution looks good. One suggestion instead of have years array defined in constructor. let's have a helper function and use that for getting list of years.

Answer (score 3):

This might help. Make sure you properly set the correct state and handle your updates in your onHandleChange.

```js
const minOffset = 0;
const maxOffset = 60; 

class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    const thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    
    this.state = {
      thisYear: thisYear,
      selectedYear: thisYear
    }
  }
  
  onHandleChange = (evt) => {
    // Handle Change Here
    // alert(evt.target.value);
    this.setState({ selectedYear: evt.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { thisYear, selectedYear } = this.state;
    const options = [];
    
    for (let i = minOffset; i <= maxOffset; i++) {
      const year = thisYear - i;
      options.push(<option value={year}>{year}</option>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.selectedYear} onChange={this.onHandleChange}> 
          {options}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class DropDown extends Component {

render() {
    let minOffset = 0, maxOffset = 10;
    let thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    let allYears = [];
    for(let x = 0; x <= maxOffset; x++) {
        allYears.push(thisYear - x)
    }

    const yearList = allYears.map((x) => {return(<option key={x}>{x}</option>)});
    return(
        <div>
            <select>
                {yearList}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

this might not be the most optimal solution by any means but this is just to give you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: It works fine, but actually the problem is, I am using the semantic ui (react) so I have a dropdown value, please have a look 

    <Form.Dropdown label={'From'} placeholder='' fluid search selection options={yearList} width={4} />

Comment: <Dropdown placeholder='Years' fluid selection options={YearsArray} />
Just put the Years array in the options and it should work fine.

Comment: As per SUI docs, I can't pass the <option> tag in this,
`
    export const yearList = [
        {key: '1970', text: '1970', value: '1970'},
        {key: '1971', text: '1971', value: '1971'},
        {key: '1972', text: '1972', value: '1972'},
        {key: '1973', text: '1973', value: '1973'},
    ]
`
this is the sample code, Its working fine
`<Form.Dropdown label={'From'} placeholder='' fluid search selection options={yearList} width={4} />`

but I want to get the dynamic years in the loop thats why I need a const to pass in the options according <Form.Dropdown options={}/>

Comment: You can use let instead of const if you think you will be changing that array. I tried it with semantic-ui-react library and it worked fine for me..

Answer (score 2):

yet another way:

```
  getDropList = () => {
    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return (
      Array.from( new Array(50), (v,i) =>
        <option key={i} value={year+i}>{year+i}</option>
      )
    );
  };
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knik/n5u2wwjg/9637/